# UUID as foriegn key in @ManyToOne hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I got error: 

`org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on xxx.yyy.zz.myentity.xxx_id references an unknown entity: java.util.UUID`

code

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "xxx_id", nullable = false, updatable = false, referencedColumnName = "xxx_id", insertable
        = false)
private UUID xxxId;
```

I got this when i change from AnotherEntity to UUID. I did this because i dont want to hold an object in my entity but only key to it(key type in AnotherEntity is UUID). I found that this error is cause when Object isnt annotated with 
@Entity annotation. Is it true? How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You can represent an `Entity` as a SQL table and fields (properties) from this `Entity` as the columns from this table.

That's the easiest way to use Hibernate (or any other JPA implementation).

When you define a relationship (OneToOne, OneToMany, ManyToOne or ManyToMany) you are linking SQL tables so, with JPA, you are linking Entities.

As you can imagine, you can't define a relationship between a table and a column.

So:

your xxxId is supposed to be an object (Entity/Table) mapped in your database and Hibernate must know the column mapping.

that's the purpose of the @Entity annotation and all @Column, @JoinColumn you can use on an Entity class.

so yes, you can't use an object in a ManyToOne relationship that is not annotated with @Entity (it would be considerate by Hibernate like a column)

therefore, you cannot use an object from the JDK (because they are not annotated with any JPA annotation)

more specifically, java.util.UUID is not a class you can change. so you have no way to tell hibernate how it can map it to a Table in your DB.

so the only way I can imagine in your case is to use an entity you created to wrappe the UUID.  For example:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="UUID")
public class UUIDWrapperEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "UUID")
    private UUID uuid;

}
```